# Pointers on extracting the Component size or Community Size on Neo4j using Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, components, size, detection

I am trying to extract the Component/Community size using my neo4j database.  Could someone share any pointer either towards built-in functions or sequence of Cypher commands using which I can extract the Component/Community sizes please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try out [neo4j graph algorithms](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-graph-algorithms) plugin, that contains algorithms, that you can call using cypher. You just download it and copy it to `/plugins` folder.

They support **(weakly) connected components**. Check the [documentation](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-graph-algorithms/#_connected_components):

get the size of connected components.

```
CALL algo.unionFind.stream('User', 'FRIEND', {})
YIELD nodeId,setId
RETURN distinct(setId) as component, count(*) as component_size
```

You can check the number of **strongly connected components**, [docs](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-graph-algorithms/#_strongly_connected_components):

example:

```
CALL algo.scc('User','FOLLOW', {write:true,partitionProperty:'partition'})
YIELD loadMillis, computeMillis, writeMillis, setCount, maxSetSize, minSetSize
```

and then search results:

```
MATCH (u:User)
RETURN distinct(u.partition) as partition,count(*) as size_of_partition 
ORDER by size_of_partition DESC LIMIT 20
```

They also support **label propagation algorithms**, [docs](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-graph-algorithms/#_graph_partitioning_label_propagation).

example call:

```
CALL algo.labelPropagation(label:String, relationship:String, 
direction:String, {iterations:1,
weightProperty:'weight', partitionProperty:'partition', write:true})
YIELD nodes, iterations, loadMillis, computeMillis, writeMillis, write, weightProperty
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  But one further question here is, what exactly it represents when we say USER or FRIEND?  Looks like these queries run on any graph database.

Comment: check the docs ... we are loading nodes by labels and relationships by their type